# Attempt number grouped by users in SQL or Python

Tags: python, sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a table similar to this (without the attempt column):

| user_id | status | date | attempt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | completed | 5/4/2022 | 1 |
| 2 | completed | 5/5/2022 | 1 |
| 1 | failed | 5/6/2022 | 1 |
| 1 | failed | 5/7/2022 | 2 |
| 2 | completed | 5/8/2022 | 1 |
| 1 | completed | 5/9/2022 | 3 |
| 2 | failed | 5/10/2022 | 1 |
| 2 | completed | 5/11/2022 | 2 |
| 2 | completed | 5/12/2022 | 1 |
| 2 | completed | 5/13/2022 | 1 |

I'm trying to figure out how to create the "attempt" column. Basically the attempt number should reset to 0 on a user's next attempt a "completed" status, specific to user_id. The example is small but the actual dataset I'm working with is large so I can't do anything super computationally intensive. I have access to the data in SQL or Python, whichever is easier

I was able to get a correct "attempt" column for a single user with the answer from this question: [Count rows with positive values and reset if negative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71668007/count-rows-with-positive-values-and-reset-if-negative)
but it didn't work when the dataframe contained multiple users.

I haven't found anything that works in SQL either. This was my most recent effort: [text](https://stackoverflow.com)question:[Attempt number over transitory statuses in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47720646/attempt-number-over-transitory-statuses-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 1):

We can address this as a gaps-and-islands problem. One way to solve it is to define groups with a window count of "previously" completed statuses, then enumerate records within each group:

```
select user_id, status, date,
    row_number() over(partition by user_id, grp order by date) attempt
from (
    select t.*,
        sum(case when status = 'completed' then 1 else 0 end) over(
            partition by user_id order by date 
            rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
        ) grp
    from mytable t
) t
order by date
```

| user_id | status | date | attempt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | completed | 2022-05-04 | 1 |
| 2 | completed | 2022-05-05 | 1 |
| 1 | failed | 2022-05-06 | 1 |
| 1 | failed | 2022-05-07 | 2 |
| 2 | completed | 2022-05-08 | 1 |
| 1 | completed | 2022-05-09 | 3 |
| 2 | failed | 2022-05-10 | 1 |
| 2 | completed | 2022-05-11 | 2 |
| 2 | completed | 2022-05-12 | 1 |
| 2 | completed | 2022-05-13 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0fEgNoxT)